# How to write ASP.NET webform data to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am a total beginner of ASP.NET. I have created a webform in Visual Studio and now I need to figure out how to make the webform submit the data to a record in SQL. I assume there are thousands of tutorials out there for this but I can't seem to find any. Everything I find seems wildly over-complicated to just simply write data to a record. (or maybe its just my lack of understanding .NET that makes it seem over-complicated.)

I dont need to exchange data, or update live data on a page form the db, I just need to write the data to a record.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try this: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077527/how-to-insert-data-into-sql-server-in-asp-net-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the scaffolding feature to generate your application.

All you need to do is setup your connection string (pointing to your database) and follow this tutorial (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-web-forms-scaffolding-in-Asp-Net/).

As simple as this!

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link: http://mrbool.com/inserting-data-into-sql-server-database-using-csharp-and-asp-net/25091

or this link

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/12611/easy-steps-to-insert-data-into-sql-server-using-Asp-NetC-Sharp.aspx